# How to get tint value of Drawable programmatically

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am able to set tint of a drawable on runtime by programmatically as `Drawable#setTintList`. My question is how to get it in order to reuse later on during runtime, or is that even valid/possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ImageView#getImageTintList()` function to get the current `ColorStateList` used to tint the image drawable, or null if no tint is applied.

you can see more on [android_documentation_for_image](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView)

Comment: Cool, but for future reference: the method is added in API level 21